# C# Linq Driver to mongoDB - Bson Array

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

My document structure contains one field as Bson Array.

I want to get all records from collection with all the Bson array values as List of Strings.

I know the below code is wrong as I am only getting first value of the Bson Array

```
 public List<String> GetRecordsfromTime(DateTime dateTime)
            {
                return _collection.AsQueryable<SocialRecord>().Where(x => x.DateCreated > dateTime).Select(x => x.TermMonitorIds[1].ToString()).ToList();
            }
```

Could some one know how to iterate through those bson array to get everything as list of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an indexer on your `TermMonitorIds` collection, so you're getting the second element of every collection of `TermMonitorIds` in your `SocialRecord` collection.

You'll want to instead do a `SelectMany` like so:

```
return _collection.AsQueryable<SocialRecord>()
                  .Where(x => x.DateCreated > dateTime)
                  .SelectMany(x => x.TermMonitorIds.ToString())
                  .ToList();
```

Edit: Since OP has said MongoDB doesn't allow SelectMany query operators.

```
// Evaluate the query
var socialRecords = _collection.AsQueryable<SocialRecord>()
                               .Where(x => x.DateCreated > dateTime)
                               .ToList();

// Return desired results.
return socialRecords.SelectMany(x => x.TermMonitorIds.ToString());
```

Comment: Yeah i tried that, problem is MongoDB LinQ Driver does not support SelectMany. Error - "The SelectMany query operator is not supported."

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code to solve this:

```
 return _collection.AsQueryable<SocialRecord>()
                           .Where(x => x.DateCreated > dateTime)
                           .Select(z => z.TermMonitorIds.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList())
                           .ToList()
                           .SelectMany(x => x)
                           .ToList();
```